# Windows Network interruptions

Tags: home-networking

I frequently access files on my laptop from my desktop over my WIFI network.

I have noticed that the windows explorer frequently 'times out'/crashes and I have to re-open it to get back to the files on my laptop.

What could be causing this and how can I ensure a more stable and seamless access to all files on all devices on my home network?

Note: Running Windows 7 on both machines. The laptop is set to never sleep when plugged in (and it is plugged in when having the issue) desktop never sleeps - I am accessing via UNC shared path

Comment: What versions of Windows are you running on your laptop and desktop?   Do you have either machine configured to go to sleep mode after x number of minutes?   that very well could be causing some of your issues.   Also, are you mapping a shared drive or are you directly accessing the folders via a UNC share path \\computer\sharedfolder?

Comment: -Windows 7 on both machines. The laptop is set to never sleep when plugged in (and it is plugged in when having the issue) desktop never sleeps - I am accessing via UNC shared path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following:

1. Click Start type regedit and then click OK.
2. Locate and then select the following key in the registry: 
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\lanmanserver\parameters
3. In the right pane, click the autodisconnect value, and then on the Edit menu, click Modify. If the autodisconnect value does not exist, follow these steps:
4. On the Edit menu, point to New, and then click REG_DWORD.
5. Type autodisconnect, and then press ENTER.
6. On the Edit menu, click Modify.
7. Click Hexadecimal.
8. In the Value data box, type ffffffff, and then click OK.

Or you can go to http://support.microsoft.com/kb/297684 and run the microsoft fix it tool and it should do the above steps for you.

I would also reccomend mapping the network drive as opposed to browsing the network resource directly.   In Windows Explorer, select Map network drive

[image]

Comment: Did everything you suggested. I guess we will wait and see if it solved the issue. Thanks for the help

Comment: let me know if it did not help, I have a few other suggestions for you to try if that does not work.

Comment: well.... I thought it did... actually seemed faster with a mapped drive. but then it did disconnect after having explorer open for an extended amount of time. I'd definitely like to try anything else you got

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by extended?   15 Minutes?   1 Hour?  Longer?

Comment: lets say 30min. Haven't actually timed it. but if i leave the window open it times out. All I have to do is re-open explorer and its back but the window can't remain open while i'm working in other windows without explorer cutting off.

Comment: Also. Same thing happens while using remote desktop connection. It 'times out' on its own and I'm forced to reconnect. I have a feeling this happens due to inactivity...

Comment: try running the following command on each system.  net config server /autodisconnect:-1

Comment: I found a post where people are discussing this issue and it seems a number of fixes are being suggested that seem to work for some and not for others.   Here is the URL http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/bdec4c88-4638-4d8c-abb1-7abb8dcaeb28/windows-7-64bit-problem-with-mapped-network-drives-locking-explorer-up?forum=w7itpronetworking

Comment: let me know if any of that stuff works

Comment: So my problem appears to have been solved. I think it may have been the net config server /autodisconnect:-1 that did the trick. Thanks again Richie086!